# When clicking on author, it shows my email address in url

Tags: author

When clicking on the author in the post, it shows my email address in the URL on the new page.
How can it be changed?
I'm using wordpress.

Comment: That's not normal Core behavior. Have you tried switching to a default theme such as Twenty Nineteen to see if it still happens? If not, you've verified it's your theme that's causing this to happen. But if it still happens, you can start deactivating plugins to find out which one is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

An URL-friendly version of your username (login) will be part of the url (slug/nicename) to your author archive page, unless your email is equal to your username.

You can change this by a plugin like [WP Author Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-author-slug/). Then make sure your display name, as found on your profile page, is something you want people to identify you with.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it with WP Author Slu